# Unable to generate azure TTS via Python on windows

Tags: python, windows, azure

so i tried to use azure cognitive speech to generate TTS but its not generating any output, this code run perfectly on ubuntu & mac but it wont work on my windows machine

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioDataStream, SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesizer, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig


close_file = "tes.wav"

closer = "placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups."
speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="API", region="asdasd")
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-GuyNeural"
audio_config = AudioOutputConfig(filename=close_file)
synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
synthesizer.speak_text_async(closer)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I made some changes to your code and got the audio output with input text on windows.***

**Code:**

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioDataStream, SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesizer, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig

try:
    close_file = "kam.wav"
    closer = "Hi kamali, I am your personal assistant. I am here to help you. "
    speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="<speech-key>", region="<speech-region>")
    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-GuyNeural"
    audio_config = AudioOutputConfig(filename=close_file)
    synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    synthesizer.speak_text_async(closer).get()
    
    print("Text successfully converted to speech.")

except Exception as ex:
    print("Error: ", ex)
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and gives the audio output with input text as below,

[image]